# Nested array of promises. What am I not understanding?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying get build data with an API call that is then used to make another API call. I can't figure out how these promises work. What am I doing wrong with the array of promises??

http://jsbin.com/pidilokexi/edit?js,console,output

```
function getFruits() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve(["apple", "orange", "banana"]);
    }, 1000);
  })
}

function processFruit(fruit) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve({ processedItem: fruit + "s" });
    }, 1000);
  })
}

function processAllFruits(fruits) {
  let newFruits = [];
  fruits.forEach(fruit => {
    processFruit(fruit).then(newFruit => {
      newFruits.push(newFruit);
    })
  })
  return newFruits;
}

function buildFruits() {
  return getFruits().then(fruits => {
    return processAllFruits(fruits);
  })
}



var fruits = buildFruits();

Promise.all(fruits).then(r => {
  console.log(r);
})

fruits.then(r => {
  console.log(r)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your processAllFruits should wait for all promises. Now it works this way: 
1) creates newFruits
2) starts processing each fruit
3) returns newFruits (which is still empty array)
4) finish processing and populating newFruits (which will not do a thing, since it was returned already)

Answer (score 1):

[`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is what you're looking for. Specifically, in this function:

```
function processAllFruits(fruits) {
  let newFruits = [];
  fruits.forEach(fruit => {
    processFruit(fruit).then(newFruit => {
      newFruits.push(newFruit);
    })
  })
  return newFruits;
}
```

you are returning the `newFruits` array synchronously, not waiting for the individual `processFruit` promises to resolve. `Promise.all()` accepts an array of promises and will resolve when all the given promises resolve:

```
function processAllFruits(fruits) {
  let newFruits = fruits.map(processFruit)

  return Promise.all(newFruits);
}
```

Here's a [working jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jomayiwozi/1/edit?js,console,output).